# Using Consolibyte PHP Quickbooks DevKit, InvoiceServices query returning false

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I used the following process:

- I created an array of invoices that span a 90 day period, from today back to 90 days ago.
- I converted those invoices into a comma separated string `$invoiceString` , with single quotations around each number
- Used `$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();` to create a new InvoiceService object.
- Created the following query to retrieve the batch of invoices from our QB's:
  `$invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber IN (" . $invoiceString . ") MAXRESULTS 1000");`

This would return false.  However if I limited the time range in which the invoices numbers were first gathered to 60 days or less it worked, but 61 days or more and it returned false.  Is there a hard limit to the number of days back the query will go?  Am I missing in the query?

Thanks in advance for any help!

***EDIT***

Here is the error code I receive when I include the debugging statements:

`ERROR: 3100: [message=InternalServerError; errorCode=003100; statusCode=500, ]`

`RESPONSE: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error Server: nginx Date: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 14:40:44 GMT Content-Type: text/xml Content-Length: 350 Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=5 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <IntuitResponse time="2017-04-13T07:40:44.030-07:00" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3"> <Fault type="SERVICE"> <Error code="3100"> <Message>message=InternalServerError; errorCode=003100; statusCode=500</Message> </Error> </Fault> </IntuitResponse>`

I'm not sure which query you are asking for.  I've already included the query I send using the InvoiceServices object.  Any previous SQL query was just used to create the invoiceString that I used in the InvoiceService batch query.  That query simply returns an array of approx. 368 invoice number that I then use to create the invoiceString, comma separated, with each invoice number surrounded by single quotes.

I could not find error code 3100 in any of the list of error codes I could find.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's logging an error (I'm not familiar with the syntax)? Doesn't the query engine support something like `BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND CURDATE()`?

Comment: My other guess is that the string may be too long. That should show up in a log though.

Comment: This is not a valid SQL query: "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber IN (" . $invoiceString . "     It's PART OF an SQL query, but we really can't tell what exactly you're doing or reproduce this because we can't see what $invoiceString is set to. In any case, if you're sure that your SQL query is valid, you should file a support ticket with Intuit -- this is an error coming from Intuit's server, as you can see in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the examples, which show you how to debug issues like this:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/debugging.php

Specifically, you can view the raw response from Intuit like this:

```
print('RESPONSE: <code>' . htmlspecialchars($BillService->lastResponse()) . '</code><br><br><br>');
```

And the last error like this:

```
print('ERROR: ' . $BillService->lastError());
```

Also, it'd be helpful if you posted an actual example of the SQL query you're running, so that we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've edited by original question to respond to this.  Thank you for the help.